# Following Learn Ruby On Rails Tutorial, Cant add users to database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, railstutorial.org

Im trying to follow the [Learn Ruby on Rails tutorial](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/) my Michael Hartl. I'm on chapter 7 which grabs user data from a database to display pages. However, I keep getting an error that there is no user with an ID of one. I can't verify the data in the database (since the sql database viewer says it cant open the file and I have no idea how to install the 1.1 version which allegedly fixes that problem).

I tried adding a user in the console and it seems to succeed, but the second I go to find the user I just created, it doesn't exist (see below). Any help? I'm very frustrated at the moment.

#### User.find

```
1.9.3-p327 :001 > User.find(1)
  User Load (31.4ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound: Couldn't find User with id=1
    from /home/gerard/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/activerecord-3.2.9/lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb:341:in `find_one'
    from /home/gerard/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/activerecord-3.2.9/lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb:312:in `find_with_ids'
    from /home/gerard/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/activerecord-3.2.9/lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb:107:in `find'
    from /home/gerard/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/activerecord-3.2.9/lib/active_record/querying.rb:5:in `find'
    from (irb):1
    from /home/gerard/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/railties-3.2.9/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:47:in `start'
    from /home/gerard/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/railties-3.2.9/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
    from /home/gerard/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/railties-3.2.9/lib/rails/commands.rb:41:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

#### User.create

```
1.9.3-p327 :002 > User.create(name: "MD", email: "md@example.com", password: "foobar", password_confirmation: "foobar")
   (22.6ms)  SAVEPOINT active_record_1
  User Exists (56.7ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE LOWER("users"."email") = LOWER('md@example.com') LIMIT 1
  SQL (153.7ms)  INSERT INTO "users" ("created_at", "email", "name", "password_digest", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5) RETURNING "id"  [["created_at", Mon, 11 Feb 2013 00:59:52 UTC +00:00], ["email", "md@example.com"], ["name", "MD"], ["password_digest", "$2a$10$NFEb9PsPQuSEGbJ8.TOILefjZMgTAJXCFHExZpGZmlov72UffjoUe"], ["updated_at", Mon, 11 Feb 2013 00:59:52 UTC +00:00]]
   (0.4ms)  RELEASE SAVEPOINT active_record_1
 => #<User id: 4, name: "MD", email: "md@example.com", created_at: "2013-02-11 00:59:52", updated_at: "2013-02-11 00:59:52", password_digest: "$2a$10$NFEb9PsPQuSEGbJ8.TOILefjZMgTAJXCFHExZpGZmlov...">
```

#### User.find

```
1.9.3-p327 :003 > User.find(1)
  User Load (2.2ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound: Couldn't find User with id=1
    from /home/gerard/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/activerecord-3.2.9/lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb:341:in `find_one'
    from /home/gerard/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/activerecord-3.2.9/lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb:312:in `find_with_ids'
    from /home/gerard/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/activerecord-3.2.9/lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb:107:in `find'
    from /home/gerard/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/activerecord-3.2.9/lib/active_record/querying.rb:5:in `find'
    from (irb):3
    from /home/gerard/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/railties-3.2.9/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:47:in `start'
    from /home/gerard/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/railties-3.2.9/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
    from /home/gerard/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/railties-3.2.9/lib/rails/commands.rb:41:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

Comment: What does `User.all` return? Make sure that a user exists with the ID you're using in `find()`

Comment: Do your unit tests work? If you don't have those, the best plan is to make some. Unit tests are essential to writing a working application and not having to pull out your hair because of problems like this.

Comment: User.all returns one entry with an ID of 3. Shouldnt I be able to create a user with an ID of 1 if such a user doesnt exist? I've been following the tutorial and all of my tests were passing, so Im not sure how I got in this mess.

Answer (score 1):

I guess, you've already run a 'rake db:migrate' in your command line and your sqlite3 database files already generated in your db folder.

Comment: In Rails console, if you run a User.save command after User.create(name:...) What's happening?

Comment: It says "undefined method save" `1.9.3-p327 :001 > User.create(name: "MD", email: "MD@email.com", password: "stuff", password_confirmation: "stuff") 
   (0.6ms)  SAVEPOINT active_record_1
  User Exists (29.1ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE LOWER("users"."email") = LOWER('MD@email.com') LIMIT 1
   (11.8ms)  ROLLBACK TO SAVEPOINT active_record_1
 => #<User id: nil, name: "MD", email: "MD@email.com", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, password_digest: "$2a$10$N6W3gWwIIwLon6fLuhgX3uLxIAdK5F5y.nfFHIG0WZuS...">
`

Comment: `1.9.3-p327 :002 > User.save
NoMethodError: undefined method `save' for #<Class:0x8cfca6c>
 from /home/gerard/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems`

Comment: You can reset your development database with rake db:reset and you can create a new User with User.create. It should get ID 1. It could happen that you create and later destroy some record in you db, than the new record get higher ID even though your db already empty.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Is that the only way to start the entries at 1 again?

Comment: You can edit your sqlite3 database directly with a database editor. In this case, you can rewrite your IDs. You can find an other table in your database, called: 'sqlite_sequence'. You will see a line there with 'users', and update the 'seq'. If you have only one record in your user database, than seq should be '1'.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are using the rails console,

If so once you add the user to the database you need to reload the console

in your rails console

```
User.create(name: "MD", email: "md@example.com", password: "foobar", password_confirmation: "foobar")

reload!

User.find(1)
```

Answer (score 1):

As @aceofbassgreg mentioned, the User.create method you ran, created a user with ID 4.

During your tutorial you've probably created and deleted some user instances. Each time you create a new user, the value of the ID field is automatically generated and it keeps increasing. It is also the primary key.

The ID column has the auto_increment attribute. It is auto determined by the RDBMS and it's incremented by 1 every time a new instance of the object is created. So, if you create 3 User objects and then delete them, even if your table is empty, the next User object will have an ID of 4. Of course, you can reset the auto_increment counter to any value with the right SQL command.

On top of that, for security reasons the create method ignores the primary key (ID in this keys) and inheritance fields when you pass them in as parameters ("mass assignment"). Because of that User.create(:id => 1) will not work.